# Node.js + peerjs not working with ssl

Tags: linux, node.js, server, peerjs

I am trying to run peerjs on node.js with SSL but it's not working for some reason.

I have installed and started peer by following instructions 
https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server

But the issue I have is when peerjs is not working over SSL
so when I access peerjs using http://example.com:9000 then it works fine but when I Use https://example.com:9000 I get this "unexpectedly closed the connection." error

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try to set the port to 443 default port for https ?

Comment: Hey Alexandru, Thanks for the response, Yes I dd.

Answer (score 0):

You'll experience this issue if you're using a self-signed certificate